# How to get HTML of a sidebar content in wordpress?

Tags: html, wordpress, menu

I can get a list of sidebars by going through `wp_registered_sidebars`

```
<?php foreach ( $GLOBALS['wp_registered_sidebars'] as $sidebar ) { ?>
     <input value="<?php echo ucwords( $sidebar['id'] ); ?>">
              <?php echo ucwords( $sidebar['name'] ); ?>
<?php } ?>
```

And I can output the sidebar with

```
<?php echo dynamic_sidebar( ucwords( $sidebar['id'] )); ?>
```

But I need to output the HTML content out.

I am trying to insert the sidebar in a menu (megamenu), and I am following [this post](http://www.johnmorrisonline.com/how-to-add-a-fully-functional-custom-meta-box-to-wordpress-navigation-menus/) on how to get the metabox appear in my Menus page. I've done it all, I can get the name, id of the sidebar, everything. It's just when I try to add HTML content in my description field of the menu, I don't know how. If I put the dynamic_sidebar I'll get the actuall sidebar in my menus page, and that's not what I want.

So any help is appreciated.

Is it possible to do it with `ob_start()` function?

**EDIT**

I tried with:

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    dynamic_sidebar($sidebar['id']);
    $sidebar_html = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
?>
```

But when I echo that variable inside the hidden input field

```
<input type="hidden" class="menu-item-description" name="menu-item[-1][menu-item-description]" value="<?php echo $sidebar_html; ?>">
```

I still get the html out. I just need it as a text html that won't be 'executed'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, `htmlentities()` did it

```
<input type="hidden" class="menu-item-description" name="menu-item[-1][menu-item-description]" value="<?php echo htmlentities($sidebar_html); ?>">
```